# symfony default access rules for new page

Tags: php, symfony

in my Symfony app I use FOSUserBundle for users authentication. Access control is made based on rules from `security.yml`. The problem is that when I create a new page (with new routing) and it is not included in `security.yml`, access to this page is graned automatically and any user may have access to it until it is not posted to `security.yml`. How to prevent this behaviour and make all my new pages when they are not shown in `security.yml` behind firewall by default? I tried to add the following line to `access_control` section:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, role: ROLE_BASE_USER }
```

but it did not work. Any ideas how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: If you need to be logged for access to an URL, use IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY instead ROLE_BASE_USER

Comment: no, I dont need to be logged in, I need to hide all my new pages behind firewall by default (not depending on the fact whether the page is in security.yml or not), and when not logged in user tries to access it, he gets redirected to login page

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `firewall rule` with `pattern` and add `prefix` to your secured and unsecured routes:

```
security:

    .
    . Some other settings here
    .

    firewalls:
        public_area:
            pattern:  ^/public
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: entity_provider

         private_area:
            pattern:  ^/private
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: entity_provider

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/public, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, methods: [POST] }
        - { path: ^/private, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/private/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, methods: [POST] }
```

[More you can read here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/firewall_restriction.html)

this code is just an example, it can contain errors :) Of course you can delete the prefix from an unsecured firewall.

To simplify the code you can declare prefixes in one place - `/config/routes/annotations.yaml`:

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation

page1:
    prefix: /page
    resource: App\Controller\Page1Controller

page2:
    prefix: /page
    resource: App\Controller\Page2Controller

page3:
    prefix: /page
    resource: App\Controller\Page3Controller
```